# What is the problem in this code Authy PHP?

Tags: php

I created an authenticator using "authy" with php, but the verification in case of wrong otp does not work.

Code:

```
include('config/otp-authy/vendor/autoload.php');

$authy_api = new Authy\AuthyApi('HIDDEN');          
$otp = $_POST['otp'];               
$verification = $authy_api->verifyToken('HIDDEN', ''.$otp.'');

if ($verification->ok()) {
    $_SESSION['HIDDEn'] = $row['userId'];
     header("Location: home.php");                  
} else {
    $error_otp = "Il codice OTP è errato!";
}
```

ERROR:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Authy\AuthyFormatException' with 
>         message 'Invalid Token. Unexpected length.' in /var/www/HIDDEN/config/otp- 
>         authy/lib/Authy/AuthyApi.php:323\nStack trace:\n#0 
>        /var/www/HIDDEN/config/otp-authy/lib/Authy/AuthyApi.php(105): 
>        Authy\AuthyApi->__validateVerify('HIDDEN', 'HIDDEN')\n#1 
>        /var/www/HIDDEN/index.php(54): Authy\AuthyApi->verifyToken('HIDDEN', 
>        '222')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/HIDDEN/config/otp- 
>        authy/lib/Authy/AuthyApi.php on line 323, referer: https://HIDDEN/index.php

Comment: What exactly is unclear? Doesn't the error message tell you pretty much?

Comment: https://coinfloor.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002284403-Why-does-the-Authy-token-return-error-Invalid-

Comment: practically gives me error of the token which is wrong, but I would like it to go on else, but it doesn't work

Comment: _Side note:_ You don't need to quote variables when passing them as a function/method argument. You can change `verifyToken('HIDDEN', ''.$otp.'')` to `verifyToken('HIDDEN', $otp)`

Comment: THX WORK  Magnus Eriksson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you change:

```
verifyToken('HIDDEN', ''.$otp.'')
```

To:

```
verifyToken('HIDDEN', $otp)
```